# How to serve non-local images from localhost

Tags: python, routes, localhost, bottle

I'm writing a Python script that works with images on the user's computer, my plan is to display these images on a webpage via bottle.py (which can change if need be) on localhost. The images and the script could be located anywhere, however serving from localhost doesn't allow me to display images with a file:/// path for security reasons, so I'm stuck as to how I can achieve this. I basically want bottle's static_file function but with multiple files and within a HTML template. Is this at all possible without moving the images?

Answer (score 0):

No, the [browser sandbox](http://www.20thingsilearned.com/en-US/browser-protection) won't and shouldn't allow this. Think about it this way: if you were able to display images from the user's computer without his explicit approval, they would be part of the DOM and what would stop a script from manipulating them or sending to a server without the user's knowledge?